# TerminateProcess not suceeding on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, process

Our C++ app launches a separate .exe ( which may start its own sub-processes) using CreateProcess as below.

```
BOOL started = ::CreateProcess(NULL,      // application
                p,         // parameters
                NULL,        // process security
                NULL,        // thread security
                TRUE,        // inherit handles flag
                0,           // flags
                NULL,        // inherit environment
                dirLP,      // inherit directory
                &startup,    // STARTUPINFO
                &procinfo);  // PROCESS_INFORMATIO
```

In case we need  cancel the "job" we use CreateToolhelp32Snapshot to iterate through the process list to find any child processes of the one we launched.

```
static BOOL TerminateProcessTree (HANDLE parentProcess,UINT exitCode) 
{ 
    BOOL            result=TRUE;
    HANDLE         hProcessSnap = NULL; 
    PROCESSENTRY32 pe32      = {0}; 
    //  Take a snapshot of all processes in the system. 

    hProcessSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0); 

    if (hProcessSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
        return (FALSE); 
     pe32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32); 

    //  Walk the snapshot of the processes
    DWORD parentID=GetProcessId(parentProcess);
    if(parentID==0){
        PrintLastError("GetProcessId");
        return FALSE;
    }
   if (Process32First(hProcessSnap, &pe32)) { 
        do{ 
            if(pe32.th32ParentProcessID==parentID){

               HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess (PROCESS_TERMINATE | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, pe32.th32ProcessID); 
               if(hProcess!=NULL){
                    BOOL terminateChildren=TerminateProcessTree(hProcess,exitCode);
                    BOOL terminatedChild = TerminateProcess(hProcess, exitCode);
                    if (!terminatedChild){
                        PrintLastError("TerminateProcess");
                    }
                    CloseHandle(hProcess);
                    if(!terminatedChild || !terminateChildren){
                        result=FALSE;
                        break;
                    }
               } else{
                   PrintLastError("OpenProcess");
               }
            }

        }while (Process32Next(hProcessSnap, &pe32)); 
    }
    CloseHandle (hProcessSnap); 
    DWORD checkCode=0;
    BOOL terminated;
    if(GetExitCodeProcess(parentProcess,&checkCode) && checkCode==STILL_ACTIVE){
        terminated=TerminateProcess(parentProcess,exitCode);
        if (!terminated){
            PrintLastError("TerminateProcess");
            result= FALSE;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As noted, this works fine on Windows 7. Windows 10 fails with "Access Denied" on the first call "TerminateProcess". Clearly something has changed in the Windows security model when it comes to processes.

Comment: Have you verified that `OpenProcess` is successful, giving a valid handle?

Comment: This seems like an awfully convoluted way to terminate a process you created. Why not just use the process handle `CreateProcess` returned in the `PROCESS_INFORMATION` struct?

Comment: @MrEricSir he says that CrateProcess is called by a child of the terminating process.

Comment: To elaborate on Alf's comment, look at [Job Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684161.aspx) on MSDN: "*After a process is associated with a job, by default any child processes it creates using CreateProcess are also associated with the job.*" So you can use `CreateJobObject()` and `AssignProcessToJobObject()` to associate the initial process with a job, then let it create whatever sub processes it wants, and then you can use `TerminateJobObject()` to terminate all processes currently associated with the job.

Comment: Obviously I was not 100% clear on my question. I am creating a process that "might" also launch some (sub-) processes. I have the handle to the "top" process. At a later point , having only the handle to the top process, I need to kill the "process tree". This can be done by enumerating processes and locating the members of this tree and calling TerminateProcess. This works perfectly fine on W7. On W10 , TerminateProcess fails with "Access Denied". I realize a solution would be to adopt "Job Objects" but I am trying to understand what part of the Windows 10 security model has changed

Comment: Added full source to TerminateProcessTree.

Comment: I think I see the problem - you're terminating each child process twice, once in the recursive call and then again just after returning.  Get rid of the double-terminate and see if that makes any difference.  (Incidentally, using GetExitCodeProcess to determine whether a process is still running or not is not safe, because the process might actually exit with STILL_RUNNING.)

Comment: For the record, though, one more reason not to do it this way: suppose that at some point in the past, another process had the same process ID as one of the processes that is now in your tree, and one or more of its children are still alive.  You're going to kill them.  (That might even be your problem, if you're inadvertently trying to kill an unrelated process that you don't have rights to.)  Conversely, your current approach has no way of identifying any descendant processes that have outlived their parent.

Answer (score 0):

The robust way to deal with controlling a *process tree* of objects is to use Job objects as noted in the comment threads.

The one thing to keep in mind is that a process can only belong to a single job, and by default any EXE that the OS determines needs appcompat help is put into a job object automatically managed by the "Program Compatibility Assistant". This makes using a Job object to manage arbitrary 3rd party EXEs a little bit more complicated (i.e. `AssignProcessToJobObject` fails for these processes).

If you are using `CreateProcess` you can make use of the flag `CREATE_BREAKAWAY_FROM_JOB`.  See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cjacks/2009/07/10/how-to-work-around-program-compatibility-assistant-pca-jobobjects-interfering-with-your-jobobjects/). This works fine as long as the target EXE has the same rights as the calling object.

For a Standard User EXE to run an EXE that might need Administrator rights (i.e. they contain a manifest which marks it as `requireAdministrator`), you have to use `ShellExecute` or `ShellExecuteEx` as calling `CreateProcess` in this case will fail. If your target EXEs are all using the proper [manifest elements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/09/10/manifest-madness/) then it won't be put into a PCA Job object.. You can use the trick of passing `SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI` which will have the side-effect of avoiding the PCA job behavior. If you are launching arbitrary 3rd party EXEs, you should use `ShellExecuteEx` and not `CreateProcess`.

```
bool SpawnProcess( const WCHAR* szExePath, const WCHAR* szExeArgs )
{
    if( !szExePath )
        return false;

    // NOTE: szExeArgs can be nullptr.

    // Get working directory from executable path.    
    WCHAR szDirectory[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    wcscpy_s( szDirectory, szExePath );
    PathRemoveFileSpec( szDirectory );

    // ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx must be used instead of CreateProcess
    // to permit the shell to display a UAC prompt asking for consent to
    // elevate when the target executable's manifest specifies a run level
    // of "requireAdministrator".
    //
    // You can only use CreateProcess if you know that the application you
    // are spawning will be at the same run level as the current process.
    // Otherwise, you will receive ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if the elevation
    // consent could not be obtained.
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {};
    info.cbSize = sizeof( info );
    info.lpVerb = L"open";
    info.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
    info.lpFile = szExePath;
    info.lpParameters = szExeArgs;
    info.lpDirectory = szDirectory;
    info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    if( !ShellExecuteEx( &info ) )
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Note that if you want to wait until this process exits, you can use:

```
bool SpawnProcessAndWait( const WCHAR *szExePath, const WCHAR *szExeArgs, DWORD *pdwExitCode )
{
    if( !szExePath )
        return false;

    // NOTE: szExeArgs and pExitCode can be nullptr.

    // Get working directory from executable path.    
    WCHAR szDirectory[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    wcscpy_s( szDirectory, szExePath );
    PathRemoveFileSpec( szDirectory );

    // See SpawnProcess for information why ShellExecute or ShellExecuteEx
    // must be used instead of CreateProcess.
    SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = {};
    info.cbSize = sizeof( info );
    info.lpVerb = L"open";
    info.fMask = SEE_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI | SEE_MASK_NOASYNC | SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
    info.lpFile = szExePath;
    info.lpParameters = szExeArgs;
    info.lpDirectory = szDirectory;
    info.nShow = SW_SHOW;
    if( !ShellExecuteEx( &info ) )
        return false;

    // Wait for process to finish.
    WaitForSingleObject( info.hProcess, INFINITE );

    // Return exit code from process, if requested by caller.
    if( pdwExitCode )
        GetExitCodeProcess( info.hProcess, pdwExitCode );

    CloseHandle( info.hProcess );
    return true;
}
```

You haven't noted if your "master" application here is using administrator or Standard User rights. Ideally it is using Standard User rights per the [User Account Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx) guidelines dating back to Windows Vista. If your app is running as Standard User, then it's likely that your code no longer works due to security improvements to keep non-Administrator malware from doing this kind of thing to other processes.

> For general appcompat questions about Windows 10, be sure to read the [Windows and Windows Server compatibility cookbook](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848074.aspx) and look back at the Windows 8.0 and Windows 8.1 material if you are jumping directly from Windows 7 to Windows 10.

Comment: The solution as noted by several people was to use the Jobs API and assign the process I create to a job, then terminate that job.